# How can I make civibuild use "Seven" as the default Drupal theme instead of "Bartik"?

Tags: developer, civicrm-buildkit, civibuild

Every time I run `civibuild create` or `civibuild reinstall` to create a local Drupal/CiviCRM development site, I find myself running `drush vset theme_default seven` afterwards so that I get the "Seven" theme instead of "Bartik" (which I find makes CiviCRM easier to use on smaller screens). This step is easy, but I find myself running `civibuild` frequently enough that I'd like to avoid the extra step in order to make my workflow more efficient.

Is there a way I can configure my local buildkit installation to run this `drush` command after running `civibuild`? Or some other way to set the default theme?

Answer (score 1):

Two options: 1) edit your own buildkit script  or 2) prepare a PR for buildkit and convonce Tim seven is a lot more useful than Bartik; I'll second that!

A third could be a config option; 3) PR a change to buildit where the theme you like become a config option when running `amp config`

Comment: We use sidebars all the time with our civi installs, so Seven wouldn't be a popular switch for me